# Regular Expression Function does not match an item

Tags: php, regex

Can someone please help me? I have this php regex function:

```
preg_replace_callback('/(<li[^>]+class=")([^"]+)("?[^>]+>[^>]+>)([^<]+)<\/a>/')
```

and I want it to match this string (which is a BootStrap Navbar Group Item):

```
<li id="menu-item-63" class="fa-home menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-63 dropdown open"><a title="Menu" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true">Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-53"><a title="Multiple Paragraph Page" href="http://localhost:8888/point/?page_id=33">Multiple Paragraph Page</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-52"><a title="Grandchild Page" href="http://localhost:8888/point/?page_id=40">Grandchild Page</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
        <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-51"><a title="Child Page" href="http://localhost:8888/point/?page_id=39">Child Page</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

The function currently works for non group items, like this. But I want it to also include the first LI item above. What the rest of the script then does is, it adds the FontAwesome classes and modifies the Link Text like below:

```
<li id="menu-item-46" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-46">
   <a title="Headers Page" href="http://localhost:8888/point/?page_id=38">
    <i class="fa-home fa"></i>
    <span class="fontawesome-text"> Headers Page</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

also, here is the complete code from where I got the regex function from: http://pastebin.com/nQttGRnr

Comment: It doesn't match either. You wouldn't by any chance be parsing HTML using regular expressions? You're asking for trouble. Consider using PHP DOM, SimpleXML or some other library to do this instead.

Comment: hm, but it really works on the non group items, but not on the group items...

Comment: As @TomFenech says, (1) neither example matched your regex when I just tested it, and (2) use a parser. Even in a "simple" nested list, trying to handle all of the scenarios with regex is a pain, at best.

Comment: @EdCottrell Impossible is the word you're looking for. ;-)

Comment: @ChrisWesseling That's it! Couldn't put my finger on it. Must need more coffee... :)

Comment: can you have a look at the complete code in the last line (pastebin)

Comment: @DanielKlose Only Chuck Norris can parse HTML with regular expressions. Regular people can't, because HTML isn't a regular language.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on trying to utilize this script. I figured my problem was that I tried to use the WP Nav Menu Settings Classes, whereas Title Attribute worked without problems!